# in updating the table in cx_oracle getting DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: python-3.7, cx-oracle

while updating the table in cx_oracle using python3.7 getting
error as below.

> DatabaseError: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

```
x=datetime.now()
cur.execute("update HMA_UTILITIES.REFRESH_DATA set REC_UPDATE_DATE="+str(x)+"STATUS="+"FINISHED"+","+"where JOB_ID="+str(id)+";")
```

Comment: I think execute command should be like this. `cur.execute("update HMA_UTILITIES.REFRESH_DATA set REC_UPDATE_DATE="+str(x)+", STATUS=FINISHED  where JOB_ID="+str(id)+";")`

Answer (score 0):

The trailing ";" should not be included in your statement. In addition, you should be using bind variables instead of literal values embedded in your SQL. So something like this:

```
x = datetime.now()
cur.execute("""
        update HMA_UTILITIES.REFRESH_DATA set 
            REC_UPDATE_DATE = :rec_update_date,
            STATUS = 'FINISHED'
        where JOB_ID = :job_id""",
        rec_update_date=x,
        job_id=id)
```

Comment: @hema see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html